# OpenLayers 3: How to calculate distance between 2 points?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Using OpenLayers 3, how can I determine the distance between two points in the Spherical Mercator (SRID: 3857) projection?

I know that `distanceTo` was used in OpenLayers 2

```
point1.distanceTo(point2)
```

I looked through the [OpenLayers 3 docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Point.html), but I'm not finding anything similar...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the Sphere object to calculate the distance between two coordinates like this:

```
var distance = ol.sphere.WGS84.haversineDistance([0,0],[180,0]); 
//20037508.34 meters
```

Sphere provides also various algorithms to calculate the distance like cosine,equirectangular etc.
You can also create the Sphere object with the radius of a different ellipsoid.

I don't know why the docs are not online, but you can check the methods available from the source code of the sphere object: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/sphere.js

I personally think that looking at the source code is the best way to find answers about OpenLayers3 ;)

Comment: The function works with the world geodesic system (wgs84 or epsg4326). If needed, use ol.proj.transform(coordinates, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326').

Comment: It is important to note that `ol.sphere.WGS84.haversineDistance` is not available in ol3 production code (current is 3.2.0). Indeed the method is not tagged as stable, hence it will only be available in `ol-debug.js`. This is also why it is not present in documentation.

Comment: With [#3222](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3222) `ol.Sphere.haversineDistance` is now flagged as API method: http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Sphere.html?unstable=true#haversineDistance Also take a look at the updated example: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/measure.html

Comment: Note the case: ```ol.sphere``` should be ```ol.Sphere```

Comment: haversineDistance needs to be called on an instance of ol.Sphere (it is not static). I did like this: var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137); var distance = wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance([lon1, lat1], [lon2, lat2]); // in meters

Comment: @Danilo yes sure, my code use already created object ol.sphere.WGS84 that is defined here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/sphere/wgs84sphere.js as ol.sphere.WGS84 = new ol.Sphere(6378137);

Comment: ol.sphere.WGS84 does not seem to be available in ol.js but only in ol-debug.js (v. 3.15.0). Relevant discussion is going on here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4954

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a fairly simple solution. I instanciate a ol.geom.LineString object between the two points and calculate the length of the line:

```
        this.distanceBetweenPoints = function(latlng1, latlng2){
            var line = new ol.geom.LineString([latlng1, latlng2]);
            return Math.round(line.getLength() * 100) / 100;
        };
```

You can then get a readable value using some formating:

```
        this.formatDistance = function(length) {
            if (length >= 1000) {
                length = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
                ' ' + 'km';
            } else {
                length = Math.round(length) +
                ' ' + 'm';
            }
            return length;
        }
```

**EDIT: New method of calcul**

Actualy, the distance can be false regarding the projection that you use.
We had a fairly long discussion about this on ol3's github, you can see it there:
https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3533

To summarize, you need to use that function in order to get exact calcul:

```
/**
 * format length output
 * @param {ol.geom.LineString} line
 * @return {string}
 */
export default function mapFormatLength(projection, line) {
  var length;
  var coordinates = line.getCoordinates();
  length = 0;
  for (var i = 0, ii = coordinates.length - 1; i < ii; ++i) {
    var c1 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[i], projection, 'EPSG:4326');
    var c2 = ol.proj.transform(coordinates[i + 1], projection, 'EPSG:4326');
    length += mapConst.wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(c1, c2);
  }
  var output;
  if (length > 1000) {
    output = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
    ' ' + 'km';
  } else {
    output = (Math.round(length * 100) / 100) +
    ' ' + 'm';
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using mapConst.wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance?  It's not available in production build.

Comment: I guess in the new version of openlayer, they introduced a way to get the correct length in the api

Answer (score 3):

Just to add one more option. This is not ol3 dependent.

```
function toRad(x) {return x * Math.PI / 180;}

function SphericalCosinus(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {

    var R = 6371; // km
    var dLon = toRad(lon2 - lon1),
        lat1 = toRad(lat1),
        lat2 = toRad(lat2),
        d = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) + Math.cos(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon)) * R;


    return d;
}
```

Comment: I've just come across this and it seems to be nice and simple but the results I'm getting appear to be way too high for the distances I'm measuring. I don't want to raise a new question but wondered if you might be able to assist me in debugging it please @JonatasWalker ?

Comment: At your service @dvmac01. Are you using `EPSG:4326`?

Comment: Not until you mentioned it ;) That seems to have done the trick. It's still returning measurements that are a little higher than reported elsewhere (Google Maps/Wikipedia) but if anything maybe it's too accurate? A colleague directed me towards this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox which explains the problem so I'm considering some kind of smoothing method and don't know if you could suggest something but thanks for the hint!

Comment: Probably worth noting that this returns a value in km!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this one for myself I hop it'll be useful, It return distance in metters:

```
function getCoordsDistance(firstPoint, secondPoint, projection) {
    projection = projection || 'EPSG:4326';

    length = 0;
    var sourceProj = mapObj.getView().getProjection();
    var c1 = ol.proj.transform(firstPoint, sourceProj, projection);
    var c2 = ol.proj.transform(secondPoint, sourceProj, projection);

    var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
    length += wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(c1, c2);

    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCoordsDistance(latlng1, latlng2) {

    var markers = [];

    markers.push(ol.proj.transform(latlng1, 'EPSG:4326', map.getView().getProjection()));
    markers.push(ol.proj.transform(latlng2, 'EPSG:4326', map.getView().getProjection()));

    var line = new ol.geom.LineString(markers, 'XY');
    var length = Math.round(line.getLength() * 100) / 100;

    if (length >= 1000) {
        length = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
            ' ' + 'km';
    } else {
        length = Math.round(length) +
            ' ' + 'm';
    }
    return length;
}
```

Comment: Your result will be in projection units, not true meters or km.  Depending on the projection used a line across Greenland would give the a similar result to a line across Africa, but in reality Greenland is much smaller than Africa so the true distance will be shorter.  ol.Sphere.getLength() or .haversineDistance() give the shortest true distances on a round planet.