# Get distance between tow points in openlayers 3 by meters

Tags: javascript, distance, openlayers-3

I want to get distance between two point by meters in openlayers 3 in enough precision .

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071490/openlayers-3-how-to-calculate-distance-between-2-points

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenLayers 3: How to calculate distance between 2 points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071490/openlayers-3-how-to-calculate-distance-between-2-points)

Comment: @NagaveerGowda the question limited to openlayers 3 feild. I implement it specially for openlayers3 . so please watch before vote.

Answer (score 2):

I implement it as the following function:

```
function getCoordsDistance(firstPoint, secondPoint, projection) {
    projection = projection || 'EPSG:4326';

    length = 0;
    var sourceProj = mapObj.getView().getProjection();
    var c1 = ol.proj.transform(firstPoint, sourceProj, projection);
    var c2 = ol.proj.transform(secondPoint, sourceProj, projection);

    var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
    length += wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(c1, c2);

    return length;
}
```